# Speech to text transcript API for Cocoa OS x

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, speech-recognition

I want to generate text transcript while recording an audio using AVAudioRecorder in OS X.

In ios, Apple opened up Speech Recognition API to generate text transcript. Are there any api to convert speech to text in OS X ?  Any sample code will be helpful for me to implement the same in OS X.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**NSSpeechRecognizer**

The NSSpeechRecognizer class is the Cocoa interface to Speech Recognition in macOS. This class provides a “command and control” style of voice recognition system, where the command phrases must be defined prior to listening, in contrast to a dictation system where the recognized text is unconstrained.

**Symbols**

**Creating Speech Recognizers** `init?()`
Initializes and returns an instance of the NSSpeechRecognizer class.

**Configuring Speech Recognizers**

`var commands: [String]?` An array of strings defining the commands for which the speech recognizer object should listen.

`var displayedCommandsTitle: String?` The title of the commands section in the Speech Commands window or nil if there is no title.

`var listensInForegroundOnly: Bool` A Boolean value that indicates whether the speech recognizer object should only enable its commands when its application is the frontmost one.

`var blocksOtherRecognizers: Bool` A Boolean value that indicates whether the speech recognizer object should block all other recognizers (that is, other applications attempting to understand spoken commands) when listening.

`var delegate: NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate?` The delegate for the speech recognizer object.

**Listening**

`func startListening()` Tells the speech recognition engine to begin listening for commands.

`func stopListening()` Tells the speech recognition engine to suspend listening for commands.

**Relationships**

Inherits From
NSObject
Conforms To
CVarArg, 
Equatable, 
Hashable

Answer (score 0):

The Speech Recognition API currently has no OS X counterpart and is available solely in iOS. In the past I began looking at CMUSphinx which works in console on a Mac and considered piping the output for use in OS X.